# Are there any ways to reduce the reusable code generated by babel.js?

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to build my website with ECMAScript 6, and I choose `babel` to be the compiler.

Now if there are two modules `modA.js` and `modB.js` as shown below:

```
// modA
class A {
    a: 1
}


// modB
class B {
    b: 1
}
```

After compiled, two new files will be generated:

```
// modA
define(["exports"], function (exports) {
    "use strict";

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

    var A = function A() {
        _classCallCheck(this, A);
    };
});


// modB
define(["exports"], function (exports) {
    "use strict";

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

    var B = function B() {
        _classCallCheck(this, B);
    };
});
```

Obviously, `_classCallCheck` function can be reuse, and in fact if I use more complex ES6 features like generators, more duplicated code will shown up.

So my question is: How can I reduce these code, maybe by moving them into a public module ?

(ps: I've used `gulp` as my build system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I reduce these code, maybe by moving them into a public module ?

Babel already did this for you with its [**runtime**](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/runtime/):

> Babel uses very small helpers for common functions such as `_extend`. By default this will be added to every file that requires it. This duplication is sometimes unnecessary, especially when your application is spread out over multiple files.
>
> This is where the `runtime` optional transformer comes in. All of the helpers will reference the module `babel-runtime` to avoid duplication across your compiled output. The runtime will be compiled into your build.
>
> ...
>
> The package `babel-runtime` is required for this transformer. Run `npm install babel-runtime --save-dev` to add it to your current node/webpack/browserify project. babel-runtime does not support AMD module loaders like RequireJS.
>
> ...
>
> Usage
>
> ```
> require("babel").transform("code", { optional: ["runtime"] });
>
> $ babel --optional runtime script.js
> ```

Comment: Thanks! It's really difficult to find this in the documentation.. But how can I use it with `gulp` ?

Comment: Well, it works, just using `require('gulp-babel')({ modules: "amd", optional: ['runtime']})`. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score -2):

To be honest, it is compiled to be optimsied to be validated on JS validators such as JSHint or JSLint. If you don't want lengthy compiled code, you can simply minify them on Javascript minifier such as 
http://jscompress.com/

Otherwise, you can simply use jQuery and write elegant Modular Javascript code.
https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/

Comment: oh, maybe you have misunderstood my question. Actually I WILL compress the code for production. I just consider it a waste of resources to store the ES6 polyfill in EACH module. It will be better if all my modules can share the same copy of polyfill.